# How to get notified when application goes background?

Tags: ios

I need to protect my application from taking screenshot before going to background. I have added a black view in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`. But when I check background applications in iOS7 simulator it is not showing the black image instead it shows the application itself as shown in image. How can I solve this? If I get notified before app goes background this problem might be solved. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: In de applicationDidEnterBackground: the viewWillDisappear is already called on the UIViewController. This might be the cause that you can't change the looks of the current UIViewController. I suggest navigating to a entirely black UIViewController rather than changing the current one. Because that is still within your possibilities (Since you probably initiated the navigationController from within your appDelegate?)

Comment: You mean to say app screenshot logic would be there in view will disappear of view controller?

Comment: Yup, that might work also.

Comment: That might work but I work in a big project its not that I will be adding the screenshot logic in 1/2 files. I need to write it in appdelegate itself.

Comment: Then navigating it to a Black UIViewController is probably the best solution you can do to make it work.

Comment: Navigating to black viewcontroller logic should be there in all the viewcontrollers right? That I don't want

Comment: No, you can put it in the applicationDidEnterBackground: And you can do all kinds of checks there. (For example if you want it only to work for your MessagesViewController then you can check for that there too, since you have full access to your navigationController)

Comment: I want this functionality for the whole application

Comment: Then this is the thing that will work for you. Don't forget to pop this viewController in the willEnterForeground so the user won't be bothered with it.

Comment: Check my answer, this should work for you for the entire app. Remember that adding a view to your current viewController is harder to manage then navigating to a new viewController and then popping it when you get back into the app.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus `viewWillDisappear:` not gets called when application goes background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve the functionality you want throughout your entire app is making your app navigate to an entirely black UIViewController. This so you cannot see anything when you long press on the homebutton and see the background applications.

These 2 functions will do the trick:

```
- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //navigate to the black view controller
    BlackViewController *controller = [[BlackViewController alloc] init];

    [yourNavigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:yourAnimationSettings];

    [controller release];   
}

- (void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //pop the black view controller so the user won't be bothered with it
    if(/*Check if your BlackViewController is the top of your navigationController stack*/)
    {
         [yourNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:yourAnimationSettings];
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely understand your concept. Screenshot will be taken before  applicationDidEnterBackground: method gets called. That is why above problem comes.

Comment: How can you prevent a user from using a second phone to make a copy of your screen? You can and will never completely prevent every single way of misusing the app the way it was meant to. If applicationWillEnterForeground: doesn't work for you. Maybe one of the other Protocol methods will? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a callback in AppDelegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground`